# java ireport passing json as expression

Tags: java, json, jasper-reports, ireport

i am following [this](http://jasperguide.blogspot.co.id/2015/05/how-to-use-json-file-with-table.html) tutorial to passing json to jrxml.
my dummy json file success parse into good looking report.

but i have trouble while passing json code to jrxml.
in [this](http://jasperguide.blogspot.co.id/2015/05/how-to-use-json-file-with-table.html) tutorial there is configuration like picture below

[image: datasource]

i tried to passing json like this

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();

String sPath = "/reports/master_standar_test_kertas.jrxml";
URL uReport = this.getClass().getResource(sPath);

String sJson = "{\"parameter\": { \"status\":\"success\" },\"data\":[{\"kode\":\"001\",\"title\":\"ENAMEL\"}]}";
System.out.println((new JSONObject(sJson)));
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(sJson.getBytes());
JsonDataSource source = new JsonDataSource(is);

params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_SOURCE, is);

JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(uReport.getPath());
JasperPrint jpPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, params,source);
JasperViewer jpView = new JasperViewer(jpPrint);
```

but i got error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression for source text: $P{net.sf.jasperreports.json.source}
```

my question :

1. I am sure my code is wrong, but i don't know the exact wrong code
2. I am realy want to understand how jasperreport works, but i am new in java, what there is any tutorial that i can read...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would try to set the [JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JsonQueryExecuterFactory.html#JSON_INPUT_STREAM) parameter instead, as it seems to be exactly what you need. The [JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_SOURCE](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/query/JsonQueryExecuterFactory.html#JSON_SOURCE) parameter can only be:

   - a resource on the classpath
   - a file from the filesystem, with an absolute or relative path
   - a url
2. Most of the resources for getting yourself familiar with JasperReports can be found on the [Jaspersoft Community](http://community.jaspersoft.com) website.
   You may find useful the:

   - [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/system/files/documentation/jasperreports-ultimate-guide-3v2.pdf)
   - The [Wiki](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/) or the [Answers](http://community.jaspersoft.com/answers) section

Comment: actually i just 3 month create desktop apps using java, please give me example code using JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM, just tiny example, please...?

Comment: Your code should do it, but just with `JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_INPUT_STREAM` instead of `JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_SOURCE`

Answer (score 0):

For the problem i got, i have my own solution, perhaps someone need the solution too.

this code

```
params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_SOURCE, is);
```

i replaced with

```
params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_SOURCE, "/path/to/file.json");
```

or replaced with http server response

```
params.put(JsonQueryExecuterFactory.JSON_SOURCE, "htttp://localhost:12345/data.json");
```